# NuxtJs app returns 401 after log in with laravel sanctum

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to build a PWA with NuxtJS and Laravel is in the backend for the API.

I use Laravel Sanctum for API auth and also I have NuxtJS auth module, I can login (I know this because it returns and sets all of the cookies) but when it's requesting to 127.0.0.8000/api/user auth it returns a 401 error.

Heres is my nuxtjs config

```js
export default {
  /*
  ** Nuxt rendering mode
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode
  */
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Nuxt target
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-target
  */
  target: 'server',

  server: {
    host: 'localhost'
  },

  render: {
    // working:
    injectScripts: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

    // HMR not working:
    // injectScripts: false,
  },

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      {charset: 'utf-8'},
      {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},
      {hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''}
    ],
    link: [
      {rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico'}
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '~/assets/storefront-ui',
    '~/assets/storefront-ui-custom',
    '~/assets/custom'
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  ** https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins
  */
  plugins: [
    {src: '~/plugins/helpers', mode: 'client'},
    {src: '~/plugins/storefront-ui', mode: 'client'},
    {src: '~/plugins/icons', mode: 'client'},
    {src: '~/plugins/plugins', mode: 'client'}
  ],
  /*
  ** Auto import components
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-components
  */
  components: true,
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
    credentials: true
  },

  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/login', method: 'post', propertyName: false },
          user: { url: '/api/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false }
        },
        tokenRequired: false,
        tokenType: false
      }
    },
    localStorage: false
  },

  router: {
    middleware: ['auth']
  },
  //
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/
  */
  build: {
    transpile: [/^@storefront-ui/],
    postcss: {
      // Add plugin names as key and arguments as value
      // Install them before as dependencies with npm or yarn
      plugins: {
        // Disable a plugin by passing false as value
        'postcss-url': true,
        'postcss-nested': {},
        'postcss-responsive-type': {},
        'postcss-hexrgba': {},
        "postcss-preset-env": {
          stage: 0,
        },
        "rucksack-css": {}
      },
      preset: {
        // Change the postcss-preset-env settings
        autoprefixer: {
          grid: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my login.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="flex h-screen items-center justify-center">
    <form ref="loginform" @submit.prevent="login()" class="w-1/4 mx-auto p-4">
      <h1 class="font-semibold mb-2 text-xl">
        Login
      </h1>
      <div class="mb-4">
        <label for="email" class="block mb-1 text-sm">Email</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          class="w-full border rounded px-3 py-2"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-4">
        <label for="password" class="block mb-1 text-sm">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          class="w-full border rounded px-3 py-2"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="bg-blue-500 text-white font-semibold py-2 px-10 w-full rounded"
      >
        Login
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        error: {},
      };
    },
    middleware: 'auth',
    mounted() {
      // Before loading login page, obtain csrf cookie from the server.
      this.$axios.$get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
    },
    methods: {
      async login() {
        this.error = {};
        try {
          // Prepare form data
          const formData = new FormData(this.$refs.loginform);

          // Pass form data to `loginWith` function
          await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: formData });

          // Redirect user after login
          this.$router.push({
            path: '/',
          });
        } catch (err) {
          this.error = err;
          // do something with error
        }
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

The routes/api.php

```js
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

And my cors.php

```js
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login', 'logout'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
 
    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my Laravel .env configuration.

I used `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN` instead of `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` which is plural.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I've edited your comment from just now into your answer. You may as well delete the comment you just posted as it's no longer needed (I've deleted my earlier comment too).

Comment: The correct setting is in PLURAL and takes a list of domains in a string, separated by commas. You can check the config.php file to see how the constant is setup

Answer (score 1):

if you are on localhost you need to add this in env file

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=127.0.0.1:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

do check your `APP_URL` settings in `.env` file as well. this can also cause 401. as this is used in session cookie key generation for session authentications.

in my case its value is:

```
APP_URL='https://example.com/api'
```

but i think `APP_URL='http://example.com'` will also work though i didn't tested it. for me with `/api` feels better as it is actually where the backend is.